# jquery clone + live issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have a piece of html that I'd like to copy and assign particular selects in a new copied chunk particular hanlders. My problem is that handler is being triggered n times I copy this chunk. Any suggestions to debug this trouble ? (total listing: [total listing](http://pastebin.com/QWQUT0Sp))

Jquery code:

```
"appendNewBlockTo" : function(oAppendTo, sFilterByCName){
    var iIndex = $("." + sFilterByCName).length/2;
    var oNewPlayerCS = $("#" + this.sTemplateBlockID).clone(false);


    // alter template before copying
    $(oNewPlayerCS).find("." + this.sClassListboxCName).addClass(sFilterByCName).attr('index', iIndex).live($.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change', function(){PlayerCS.enableSListbox(sFilterByCName, iIndex);});
    $(oNewPlayerCS).find("." + this.sSpecListboxCName).addClass(sFilterByCName).attr('index', iIndex);
    $(oNewPlayerCS.removeAttr('id').removeAttr('style')).appendTo(oAppendTo);
},
```

HTML chunk to be copied many times:

```
<div id="playerCSTemplate" style="display:none;">
    <select class="class_listbox">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Class</option>
        <option class="class_value" value="1">mage</option>
        <option class="class_value" value="2">priest</option>
    </select>

    <select class="spec_listbox" disabled>
        <option value="0">Unknown</option>
        <option class="spec_class class_specs_1">Frost</option>
        <option class="spec_class class_specs_1">Fire</option>
        <option class="spec_class class_specs_2">Holy</option>
        <option class="spec_class class_specs_2">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `clone(true)` - the true indicates that the elements should be cloned, along with the events they have set on them. You are then adding more events to the clones, hence the duplication.

Change the line to:

```
var oNewPlayerCS = $("#" + this.sTemplateBlockID).clone(false);
```

Or you can omit the `false` if required, as it is the default anwyay.

Alternatively, you can leave the `clone(true)` and simply not add the events to it.

Comment: $("#" + this.sTemplateBlockID).clone(true);
In this line I simply clone this html chunk, which hasn't been assigned to any handlers; i changed it to false - same result